# flot: How to hide multy-yaxes

Tags: flot

in my "overview" simple-line-chart, I do not want to display yaxes.

The following code does not help:

```
yaxes: { show: false, ticks: [] }
```

It probably works for **yaxis**, but not for **yaxes**.

I guess I need to hide each axis, but how do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `yaxes` property needs an array of objects (one for each axis). So, use

```
yaxis: { show: false, ... }
```

for one axis and

```
yaxes: [ { show: false, ... }, { show: false, ... }, ... ]
```

for multiple axes.

Comment: Thank you for your useful Flot answers!